# Show that the sum $\sum_{k = 0}^n 2^k \binom{n}{k}$ is equal to $3^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

How can I show that the sum

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^n 2^k \binom{n}{k}$$

is equal to $3^n$?

Comment: Because it's $(1 + 2)^n$.

Comment: T. Bongers means "binomial theorem".  Maybe Fourier wants a combinatorial interpretation.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought, but how do I get there?

Comment: This is like early calculus, but I've forgotten most of it, so need someone to refresh my memory :l

Answer (score 6):

For a combinatorial interpretation: suppose you have $n$ distinguishable eggs, and you want to paint some of them red, some of them blue, and leave some of them unpainted. Show that both sides of your desired equation count the number of ways to do this.

Comment: Great thanks! Made me remember that I could just add 1^(n-k), and then get (1+2)^n